# What is the Rust way of keeping borrowed values in a collection?

Tags: rust

In this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut persons = Vec::<Person>::with_capacity(3);
    let mut personrefs = Vec::<&Person>::with_capacity(persons.capacity());
    for x in 0..persons.capacity() {
        let person = Person {
            name: format!("Alice-{}", x),
        };
        personrefs.push(&person);
        persons.push(person);
    }
    println!("persons are {:#?}", persons);
}
```

I *sort of* understand why Rust wouldn't allow pushing `&person`, but what is the Rust way of solving this?

I have a `Vec` that "owns" `Person`s, but I'd also like to map persons to some other data without touching the owning `Vec` or duplicating `Person`s in memory. Like, have a `collections::HashMap<&Person, SomeOtherData>`. If both `HashMap` and `Vec` have the same lifetime, wouldn't Rust know when to deallocate `Person`s?

Comment: You will struggle a lot trying to do this. Box your struct and use `Rc`, it will be much more simple to handle that.

Comment: It is quite possible to have a vector of references ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b64e42c7bb3b5699d9b6ba7da2339449&version=stable)). You just have to be aware how to construct them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Rust way" is the way that doesn't lead to memory unsafety. Your code is invalid, as the compiler tells you:

```
error[E0597]: `person` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:26
   |
13 |         personrefs.push(&person);
   |                          ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
14 |         persons.push(person);
15 |     }
   |     - `person` dropped here while still borrowed
16 |     println!("persons are {:#?}", persons);
17 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

You are creating a `Person` inside the loop, taking a reference to it, then **moving the `Person` to a new memory address**, invalidating the reference. If you accessed that reference, you'd be touching undefined memory, leading to segfaults at best or "strange behavior" / security vulnerabilities at worst.

Likewise, you can't add the person to the `Vec` and then take a reference to that person in the loop because a subsequent iteration of the loop will mutate the vector. When you push to a vector, it might reallocate memory, again invalidating your references.

I'd write this code as

```
fn main() {
    let persons: Vec<_> = (0..3)
        .map(|x| Person {
            name: format!("Alice-{}", x),
        })
        .collect();

    let personrefs: Vec<_> = persons.iter().collect();
    println!("persons are {:#?}", persons);
}
```